# ios opencv cvReleaseImage - when does it release the memory?

Tags: ios, opencv, memory-leaks

I am new to opencv. I am integrating it into my ios project.
In my project I am converting from UIImage to IplImage and vice versa.
I am also applying different image filters using the openCV library.

I am testing my app for leakages. I am running with memory monitor and I notice that my app grows by approximatly 1 megabyte each time I run my opencv set of functions.
Everytime I allocate a new iplimage I later on release it by calling:

```
cvReleaseImage(&iplimage);
```

I am using simulator to force low memory warnings and thus release image memory.
It doesn't seem to influence my app's memory size.

When does cvReleaseImage really free the memory? Am I leaking?

I am using ios 5.1 with ARC turned on.

Edit:

This is the code I am using (some copy paste I found) to convert UIImage to iplImage

```
- (UIImage *)UIImageFromIplImage:(IplImage *)image {
    NSLog(@"IplImage (%d, %d) %d bits by %d channels, %d bytes/row %s", image->width, image->height, image->depth, image->nChannels, image->widthStep, image->channelSeq);

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:image->imageData length:image->imageSize];
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef)data);
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(image->width, image->height,
                                        image->depth, image->depth * image->nChannels, image->widthStep,
                                        colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault | kCGImageAlphaLast ,
                                        provider, NULL, false, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
    UIImage *ret = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

cvReleaseImage is definitely freeing the memory the moment it is called. It calls the dellocator for the two parts of the image:

- data
- image header

If your app reports memory leakages, you should check the whole code - maybe you create 2 images, and release one, or whatever.

Comment: I've just posted my code, I trace it through using both debugger and instrument's memory profiler and yet no memory is released.